# row numbers and content do not match up

Tags: r

I have a `dataframe "InorganicNoStdConditionResiduals"` and have the following code:

```
  View(InorganicNoStdConditionResiduals[,"Job..R"]) #gives a column with 46 rows and two different character --> [1] "14047/1" "18331/3" (correct)

  print(head(levels(InorganicNoStdConditionResiduals[,"Job..R"]))) 
  [1] "14047/1"  "14047/11" "14047/2"  "18331/2"  "18331/3"  "18331/4"
  # the answer should be: [1] "14047/1" "18331/3"
  test = levels(InorganicNoStdConditionResiduals[,"Job..R"]) #The environment view panel in RStudio tells me that there are 4794 character (4794 rows, but there are only 46 rows as verified withe View() command earlier)
  test1 = nrow(InorganicNoStdConditionResiduals)
  print(test1)
  [1] 46 # this is correct
```

Could it be that there is some stuff saved in the `workspace` which is interfering?

Comment: Does replacing `levels()` with `unique()` do what you want?

Comment: `@GSee` `print(unique(InorganicNoStdConditionResiduals[,"Job..R"]))` gives [1] 14047/2 18331/3
4794 Levels: 14047/1 14047/11 14047/2 18331/2 18331/3 18331/4 18331/5 18331/6 24012 24779/1 24889/3 ... 40558/9 (sort of what I want) then I do: `test = unique(InorganicNoStdConditionResiduals[,"Job..R"])` and the environment view panel in R studio says that test is a factor. Now I'm wondering if I need to convert column `"Job..R" into `character`

Comment: `@GSee` Using `unique()` and converting column `"Job..R"` into character using `as.character()` gives me: [1] "14047/2" "18331/3"!! How can I retrieve the number of the answer as an integer? In this case the integer would be 2 so I can use this number for further calculations!!

Comment: It sounds like at some point you've done some filtering of the material in the data.frame. You could re`factor` it with something like `INSCR[,'Job..R'] <- factor(INSCR[,'Job..R'])` (shortened). (Try this: `foo <- data.frame(aa=letters[1:4]); levels(foo); foo <- foo[1:2,,drop=FALSE]; levels(foo); foo` and you can see what is going on.)

Comment: To convert something like '13881/3' as an integer, are you trying to get the quotient (meaning 4627) or the level (2 of two levels)?

Comment: `@r2evans` My output is ` [1] "14047/2" "18331/3"` and these are 2 characters or 2 levels! Now I would like to use the `amount of characters` in this case `2` for further calculations. For example: 15 - 2(amount of character coming from my output) = 13.